# Add same values in mysql with two parameters sql

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli, sum

I have a table trade as follows:-

```
bm  | m   | price | amount | total    | status
USD | BTC | 0.01  | 1      | 0.01     | active
USD | BTC | 0.01  | 2.5    | 0.025    | active
USD | BTC | 0.4   | 0.5    | 0.020    | active 
USD | BTC | 0.4   | 0.22   | 0.088    | active
```

I want to add amounts of duplicate price i.e 0.01 and 0.4 as well as total together in one output where status is active and show them so that the result is like:-

```
price | amount  | total
0.01  | 3.5     | 0.035
0.4   | 0.722   | 0.108
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group according to the `price` and `sum` the other columns:

```
SELECT   price, SUM(amount), SUM(total)
FROM     trade
WHERE    status = 'active'
GROUP BY price
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the comma ,  from the result?

Comment: @JeffB what comma?

Comment: Let's say result is 7,000 ... but i want result to be only 7000 without comma ,

Answer (score 1):

try this with group by:

```
select price, sum(amount) as amount,sum(total) as total
from tablename where status='active'
group by price
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the comma ,  from the result?

Comment: Lets say result is 7,000.00 ...I want only 7000 without comma

Answer (score 1):

you could use aggregation function sum() and group by price

```
select   , price , sum(amount) , sum(total) 
from my_table  
group by   price
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the comma ,  from the result?

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
SELECT *, sum(amount) AS totalAmount,sum(total) AS total 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY price;
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the comma ,  from the result?

Comment: You can't use `*` for this query in any flavour of SQL I know. You are returning `bm` and `m` which are not aggregated. You could either specify `price` instead of `*` or `group by bm, m, price`

Comment: Lets say result is 7,000.00 ...I want only 7000 without comma